# How to combine columns from base table with user table created based on user registration

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, metaclass

I had a BaseModel of table defined like this:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    """
    a base model for other database tables to inherit
    """
    __abstract__ = True
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(),
                              onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
```

Now this is base table for `Users` table and `ApiKey` table, but another table I create when user registers 
so the new table is created dynamically based on email address.

```
# if user exists get table name
        user_table_name = user_exists.email.replace("@", "_").replace(".", "_")

        # Check if table for the user exists.
        if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine, user_table_name):
             metadata = MetaData(engine)
             user_table = IpMap(user_table_name, meta,
                Column("ipaddress", CIDR, nullable=False),
                Column("urlmap", String(10), nullable=False, unique=True),
                Columnb("port", Integer, unique=True, index=True),
                Column("device", String(10)),
                Column("path", String(30)),
                Column("service_name", String(10)),
                Column("count_updates", Integer)
                )
             user_table.create(engine)
        else:
            meta = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
            user_table = meta.tables[user_table_name]
```

so for this user email based table I also want to take advantage of `BaseModel`, so I chose to create my own table and subclass both `sqlalchemy.Table` and `BaseModel` which subclass `db.Model`.

but this throws an error.

```
    class IpMap(Table, BaseModel):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

and I am not able to even start my flask app. How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whatever you are trying to do will work, as combining complex classes from complex hierarchies is in no way guaranteed to work.

In this case, although you don't mention it, you are trying to combine `db.Model` which I take to be the class used by flask_sqlalchemy with sqlalchmey.table - both classes are "full of magic tricks" and this include that each have a different metaclass.

Python won't instantiate classes that inherit from independent metaclasses - instead you will get the "metaclass conflict" error you just saw. But, if metaclasses are written in a way that it is possible that they are collaborative, it is a matter of combining both metaclasses, which can be done in a single line of code.

Looking at the source code for the metaclass of `sqlalchemy.Table`, which is `VisitableType` in [this file](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py), we see that it indeed makes use of `super` where it matters. That should be all it takes for the class to be collaborative - although one can't be sure that there won't be conflicts in attribute names or other custom mechanisms implemented by the metaclasses.

Anyway, that checked, all that is needed for your code to build and you be able to inherit from both classes is to create the combined metaclass:

```
class Meta(type(sqlalchemy.Table), type(db.Model)): pass
```

And then, this should work:

```
class IpMap(Table, BaseModel, metaclass=Meta):
     ...
```

(I will paste a complete snippet bellow so that others studying this problem have some self contained code for their experiments)

```
import flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlalchemy

app = flask.Flask("bla")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="sqlite://"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
print (f"metaclass for db.Model: {type(db.Model)}")
print (f"metaclass for sqlalchemy.Table: {type(sqlalchemy.Table)}")

# This will raise a metaclass conflict:
class A(sqlalchemy.Table, db.Model):
    pass

# combining the metaclasses
class Meta(type(sqlalchemy.Table), type(db.Model)): pass


# Working example 
# (with dummy primary key filed, otherwise one gets an sqlalchemy error)
class B(sqlalchemy.Table, db.Model, metaclass=Meta):
   id  = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.INT, name="id", primary_key=True)
```

Comment: what I wanted is to create `user_table ` with `userid` , `date_created` and  `date_modified` field as well , coming from the `BaseModel` class.